# Custom Subscript in Swift not working with Implicitly Unwrapped Optional

Tags: swift, swift3, subscript

Consider the following Swift struct:

```
struct A {
    var data: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]

    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return data[index]
        }
        set {
            data[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

This is working as expected:

```
var x = A()
x[0] = 5
x.data[1] = 7
print(x.data) // prints [5, 7, 3]
```

But when I declare the variable as implicitly unwrapped optional the subscipt setter doesn't seem to work:

```
var y: A! = A()
y[0] = 5
y.data[1] = 7
print(y.data) // prints [1, 7, 3]
```

What is happening here? Shouldn't the subscript work the same way with implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior with `class A` instead of `struct A`? I have no access to swift3 yet, so I cannot verify the behavior for myself.

Comment: With `class A` the output is `[5, 7, 3]`.

Comment: [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md), you need to write explicitly `y![0] = 5`

Comment: I do not yet see the immediate connection with SE-0054, if `y[0] = 5` were invalid then it should not compile.  And it works as expected with IUO arrays: `var a: [Int]! = [1, 2, 3] ; a[0] = 5 ; print(a)` produces `[5, 2, 3]`.

Comment: This is not a new behavior. I see the same problem in Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate, this looks identical to the previously reported problem to me. (Let me know if you disagree.)